# Case-sensitivity and OS/file system

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, case-sensitive

ALL,

I know that Windows/NTFS is case-incensitive, OSX can be either case-sensitive or case incensitive and Linux is case sensitive.

Now, it looks like I can change Windows/NTFS to become case sensitive.

Is there any other OS/FS pair that can be both?

P.S.: I am sorry for the question to be too broad, but it just a nature of the question. I am unfortunately not a system-side developer and need to know this to learn.

TIA!

Comment: What do you mean by "do both"? At the same time? or per configuration? Is OSX/HFS not already doing that, as you mentioned in the question?

Comment: @root, OSX can be configured to be use either case-sensitive FS or case insensitive FS. Windows 10 can configure a folder to be case sensitive. And so I think can be HFS on Mac. So is there any other OS/FS that can either support both or be configured to support one or another?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you have [XFS](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mkfs.xfs.8.html), [JFS](http://jfs.sourceforge.net/project/pub/mkfs.jfs.html), and some [support in ext4](https://winaero.com/blog/linux-kernel-5-2-is-out-with-case-insensitive-ext4-option/).

That said, using a case-insensitive filesystem is not a good idea in development, because if the other developers *do* run on a case-sensitive files system, it could break the build.

**EDIT**

here's a script to test for case-sensitivity:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir $1/my-case-test
touch $1/my-case-test/a
if stat $1/my-case-test/A &>/dev/null; then
    echo "case-insensitive"
else
    echo "case-sensitive"
fi
rm -r $1/my-case-test
```

Run it with

```
bash test_case_sensitivity.sh /my/writeable/directory
```

And it will tell you whether or not the directory case sensitive.

Comment: that's why I need the function that will return case-sensitivity. I understand it will be OS/FS dependent, but at least I will know where and how to test it.